# Opentok React: How to call the getStats method of Publisher object of OTPublisher?

Tags: reactjs, opentok, tokbox

I am trying to use my already existing tokbox session and publishing stream to get the stats at specific times(click of a button etc).

The main documentation on tokbox.com talks about this provides a way to do it, but that is not accessible using [react tokbox](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react)

Here is what the code looks like. First is creating a session

```
startTokBox = (sessionData) => {
  const { webrtc_api, webrtc_session_id, webrtc_token } = sessionData.webrtc_details || {};
    this.tokbox = createSession({
      apiKey: String(webrtc_api),
      sessionId: webrtc_session_id,
      token: webrtc_token,
      onStreamsUpdated: (streams) => {
        this.setState({ streams });
      },
    });
}
```

Then using it in jsx

```
<OTPublisher
  session={this.tokbox.session}
  properties={{
    publishAudio: this.state.audio,
    publishVideo: false,
    ...this.publisherProperties,
  }}
  ref={this.otPublisher}
  eventHandlers={{
    streamCreated: this.onMyStreamCreated,
  }}
  onError={this.onError}
/>
```

The documentation asks to call the getPublisher method to get the Publisher instance for using Publisher methods (through which I suppose getStats will be available), but I am not sure how to do that. Any help would be much appreciated.

*P.S: I don't really want to use [opentok-network-test](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-network-test-js) and create a new instance just for testing*

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to solve this. I am leaving the question up here for if someone else faces the same problem.

What you do is, in addition to the above code, you don't forget to initialise the reference in the constructor (like i did)

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.otPublisher = React.createRef();
}
```

And then you access that reference after component mounts, or wherever you are creating a session inside the component. For instance, the first code block in the question would now look like this,

```
startTokBox = (sessionData) => {
  const { webrtc_api, webrtc_session_id, webrtc_token } = sessionData.webrtc_details || {};
    this.tokbox = createSession({
      apiKey: String(webrtc_api),
      sessionId: webrtc_session_id,
      token: webrtc_token,
      onStreamsUpdated: (streams) => {
        this.setState({ streams });
      },
    });

    this.otPublisher.current.getPublisher();
}
```

And then if you want to get the stats, then that's a function and can look like this.

`this.otPublisher.current.getPublisher().getStats((err, stats) => console.log('stats', err, stats));`

More info and help on this ticket: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react/issues/49